# Javascript RegExp Selector for HTML Template Strings

Tags: javascript, html, regex, templates

I need some help with my JavaScript regex. I need a way to select the following:

```
${user.name}
${user.age}
```

from the following html:

```html
<tr>
    <td>${user.name}</td>
    <td>${user.age}</td>
</tr>
```

There could be multiple `<td>` with different values in them and the 'user' part of the string is not always going to be user. It could be anything.

Ideally I would like them back as an array, although at the moment I'll settle for anything.

Comment: wasn't it a better approach, processing a table cell collection of a given DOM fragment instead of handling the entire fragment as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not regex expert but I hope it will work.

```
var str = "your html"
var matches = str.match(/\${[a-zA-Z0-9.]+}/g);
```

For your given input html, output will be

```
["${user.name}", "${user.age}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I write this function for your purpose:

```
    /**
     * This function assumes html with template syntax as a argument
     * and returns array from this marks.
     * Example of usage:
     *  If you have html markup like this:
     *   <table>
     *    <tr>
     *     <td>${user.name}</td>
     *     <td>${user.age}</td>
     *   </tr>
     *  </table>
     *
     * and call function with document.body.innerHTML as a argument
     *  console.log(getTemplates(document.body.innerHTML.toString()));
     * You will get the following result:
     *  Array [ "${user.name}", "${user.age}" ]
     *
     * @param input html string with template marks - ${variable.name}
     * @returns {Array} - all marks
     * @author Georgi Naumov
     * gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and suggestions.
     */
    function getTemplates(input) {
        return (input.match(/\$\{[^}\s]+\}/g) || []);
    }
    console.log(getTemplates(document.body.innerHTML.toString()));
```

You will get result in this form:

```
Array [ "${user.name}", "${user.age}" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  //  \$\{    ... search for occurrence of template string opener sequence,
  //  ([^.]+) ... then memorize every character (at least one) that is not a dot,
  //  \.      ... look for a single dot - the divider of your template string's sub-domains,
  //  ([^.]+) ... then again memorize every character that is not a dot,
  //  \}      ... finally identify the template string delimiter sequence.
  regXTemplateString = (/\$\{([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\}/),

  // make array from any derived html table cell element collection.
  tableCellList = Array.from(yourTableRowHTMLElement.getElementsByTagName('td')),

  // reduce table cell array to a data structure that one can work with further
  viewList = tableCellList.reduce(function (collector, tdElement) {
    var
      executedTemplate = regXTemplateString.exec(tdElement.innerHTML);

    if (executedTemplate) {

      collector.push({
        templateElement : tdElement,            // the html element reference
        domainName      : executedTemplate[1],  // e.g. "user" from "${user.name}"
        identifier      : executedTemplate[2]   // e.g. "age"  from "${user.age}"
      });
    }
    return collector;

  }, []);

// do whatever you're pleased with `viewList`.
```